# Rails, Javascript Re-route with Domain Variable or Relative Route

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, frontend, vis.js

I am trying to create a domain specific route in javascript.

To provide some background:
I am using a click event in visjs, my back-end is rails

```
network.on("click", function(obj) {
      // select node data, get id and us it in URL
      // here I will redirect the user to another page
      // window.location.href = "http://example.com/new_url";

});
```

In side this function I would like to be able to do is concatenate a variable and build the link, something like this:

```
  window.location.href = "http://" + Domain + "/new_url";
```

However, the domain could vary depending on the customer.
I am looking for a good way to do this without having to hard code each domain, even that would require some sort of additional conditions statement.

Is there a way I could do this from a relative route? Not sure if that is the right term, something that would not require me to create the whole route but only the part after the given domain name.

Answer (score 0):

Prior to changing

```
window.location.href
```

it has a value including the domain. I can just set that to a variable, concatenate the rest of the path and then apply it back to the same window object/key.